# How to send data from Arduino to Odoo?

Tags: arduino, iot, odoo-15

I have set up an Arduino with some sensor and I am reading those data. Now I want to send it to odoo. My best guess is that I did something wrong with this,

> client.connect(server, 4404)

My current arduino code,

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Ethernet.h>

// all vars are dummy

byte mac[] = { 0xAA, 0xAA, 0xAA, 0xAA, 0xAA, 0xAA };
    
IPAddress server(198, 11, 11, 11); 
IPAddress ip(192, 11, 11, 11);

char   HOST_NAME[] = "https://xyz-test200.odoo.com";

EthernetClient client;

String PostData = "https://xyz-test200.odoo.com/xmlrpc/2/common/POST/'x_1'='5.00'&'x_2'='myfvrtstring'"; 

void setup() {

  Serial.begin(9600);
  while (!Serial) {
    ; // wait for serial port to connect.
  }

  Ethernet.begin(mac, ip);
  
  delay(1000);
  Serial.println("connecting...");
  // we need server and port
  // in odoo doc the server is mentioned, but I am not sure about port number 
  // I put 4404 as it should be the default for xmlrpc
  if (client.connect(server, 4404)) {
    Serial.println("connected");

    client.println("POST /xmlrpc/common HTTP/1.1");
    client.println("Host: 192.168.1.2:8169");
    client.println("User-Agent: Arduino/1.0");
    client.println("Connection: close");
    client.print("Content-Length: ");
    client.println(PostData.length());
    client.println();
    client.println(PostData);
    client.println();
  } else {
    Serial.println("connection failed");
  }
}
```

Here is the [documentation](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/15.0/developer/api/external_api.html) for Odoo Rest API if anyone is interested and I tried it with python script, it works like a charm!

Comment: Can you add some debug prints so we know more about what errors are occurring.  Googling, I get the impression the default host port for Odoo is _8069._

Comment: @mmixLinus I tried with your port number and it also fails. I tried with curl, where the site was like this "https://site:port" and the error is 
" Failed to connect to site.com port 8069 after 21081 ms: Timed out ". Thanks!

Comment: hmm, why does your `String PostData` start with `hhttp:`?  A typo?

Comment: Its just a typo here and in the main code it is fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When connecting to an HTTPS server, you need an HTTPS-ready client.
HTTPS has port 443. You are currently using 4404.

If you host odoo yourself, you could create an HTTP endpoint for internal use. And then, I would also recommend creating a custom controller for more uncomplicated communication because RPC is a bit hard to do in a microcontroller.

https://forum.arduino.cc/t/ethernet-post-data-via-https/584139/3